# best way to use dispatch query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im new to parse and swift but from what Ive read of the API this is how a job queue in Parse should look? I'm fairly confused if this will allow multiple jobs to be done as they are ordered in the queue. Will this ensure that different users interact with the server in the right order?

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        var q = PFQuery(className: "User")
        q.whereKey("email", equalTo: "email@email.com")
        var array = q.findObjects()
        println(array)

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}
```

Comment: The global queues (`dispatch_get_global_queue`) are parallel, not serial, so operations may execute at the same time.

Comment: so would i need to make a custom queue to do serial operations?

Comment: If you want to do them in order, but on a background thread, then yes you can/should create a custom queue. You can either use [dispatch queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) or [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/).

Comment: Like I said, new to parse... so background is only better because of performance?

Comment: It's nothing specific to Parse. I would recommend reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH6-SW2

Comment: Thanks, gotta love the documentation